# normal distribution in a biostatistics

Tags: statistics

Among a large group of coronary patients it is found that their serum cholesterol levels approximate a normal distribution. It was found that 10% of the group had cholesterol levels below 182.3 mg per 100 ml where as 5% had values above 359.0 mg per 100ml.What is the mean and standard deviation of the distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You already know that cholestrol levels (mg/100 ml) follows nomal distribution. The only unknowns are the mean, $\mu$, and variance, $\sigma^2$ of the normal distribution. You got two equations to solve or the two unknowns:
$$P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}<\frac{182.3-\mu}{\sigma}\right)=0.1$$
$$1-P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}<359.0\right)=0.05$$
that is 
$$\frac{182.3-\mu}{\sigma}=\Phi^{-1}(0.1)$$ 
$$\frac{359.0-\mu}{\sigma}=\Phi^{-1}(0.95)$$
Now you can easily solve these two equations to get $\mu$ and $\sigma$. (Here $\Phi$ is the standard normal cdf and $\Phi^{-1}$ is obviously the quantile function of the standard normal distribution).